# jQuery UI CSS styles not being applied to menu bar generated with getJSON

Tags: jquery, css, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to generate a jQueryUI menubar using JSON data. The JSON is being parsed correctly into valid HTML; however, the menubar displays as an unstyled unordered list and not as a styled menubar as the top one seen on http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/demos/menubar/default.html. Note that the routine which converts the JSON data to HTML does not go deeper than one menu level at this time, so the sub-menu options (Open, Save, Close, etc.) are intentionally not read.

For some reason, if I hard-code the exact same HTML as what is generated by the jQuery method below in `menuBar.jsp`, the menubar styling displays just fine.

Here is the main page (`appFrameNew.jsp`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>    

<title>Menu Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/themes/base/jquery.ui.menubar.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.menubar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="layout" class="layout">

       <jsp:include page="menuBar.jsp" flush="true" />

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is `menuBar.jsp`:

```
<div class="demo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.text() == 'Quit') {
            $(this).menubar('destroy');
        }
    }
    $(function() {
        $("#bar1").menubar({
            position: {
                within: $(".demo").add(window).first()
            },
            select: select
        });
    });

$.getJSON('menuBarTestJSON.json', function(data) {
    var output='<ul id="bar1" class="menubar">';
    for (var i in data.menuOptions) {
        output+='<li><a href="#">' + data.menuOptions[i].menubarItem + '</a></li>';
    }
    output+="</ul>";
    $(".demo").html(output);
});

</script>

<ul id="bar1" class="menubar">
    <li>
        <a href="#File">File</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Open">Open</a>
            <li><a href="#Save">Save</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And lastly, `menuBarTestJSON.json`:

```
{"menuOptions":[
    {
        "menubarItem":"File",
        "menuElement": {
            "option":"Open",
            "option":"Save",
            "option":"Close",
            "option":"Quit"
        }
    }
]}
```

I've been futilely searching the web for a solution for a few days now and need to move on in this project as soon as possible. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either:

1. Add your code that initializes jQuery UI menu to the getJSON
   callback or
2. Use http://api.jquery.com/live/ to watch for changes to the DOM and initialize jQuery UI menu

Basically what's happening is that $("#bar1").menubar kicks in once, on ready.  But then when you update its contents, it doesn't know it needs to kick in again.  You have to manually ask it to initialize the menu again, or have it watch for changes.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.text() == 'Quit') {
            $(this).menubar('destroy');
        }
    }
    function initMenu() {
        $("#bar1").menubar({
            position: {
                within: $(".demo").add(window).first()
            },
            select: select
        });
    }
    $(function() { initMenu(); });

   $.getJSON('menuBarTestJSON.json', function(data) {
       var output='<ul id="bar1" class="menubar">';
       for (var i in data.menuOptions) {
            output+='<li><a href="#">' + data.menuOptions[i].menubarItem + '</a></li>';
       }
       output+="</ul>";
       $(".demo").html(output);
       initMenu();
   });

</script>
```